# Python program to find out if a number is power of 3: Giving incorrect output

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def if_powerof_3(n):
    var = None
    power  = 0
    if n % 3 == 0:
        while var == 1:
            var = n / 3
            power = power + 1
            if not var % 3 == 0:
                return "{} is not a power of 3".format(n)
                break
            else:
                n = var
        else:
            return "{} is a power of 3".format(n)
    else:
        return "{} is not a power of 3".format(n)

print if_powerof_3(18)
```

**Output : 18 is a power of 3**

It is totally unexpected and a wrong output obviously but not able to figure where is my code going logically wrong and printing a mathematically incorrect output

Comment: `var = None`, so `while var == 1` is **always going to be false**. Ergo, the `else` block of the `while` is always going to be executed when a number is divisible by 3.

Comment: please indent the code correctly

Comment: @scharette: where did you find the indentation incorrect...can you plz point out?

Comment: See the edit history

Comment: @nomoreabond2017: it was incorrect until I edited your post.

Answer (score -1):

why are you using so many if else it can be done much simpler like this

```
def if_powerof_3(n):
    var = n
    power  = 0
    while var>1:
        if var%3 ==0:
            var=var/3
            power=power+1
        else:
             return "{} is not a power of 3".format(n)
    return "{} is a power of 3".format(n)
print (if_powerof_3(27))
```

Comment: Maybe he is new. And for the kind of situation he is trying to achieve, his is just fine.

Answer (score -1):

https://gist.github.com/bondnotanymore/9afc91cb1730c9b9f637326fafc69371

This is improved piece of code with a little more robustness added.

**Output**

```
C:\Python27\python.exe 
C:/Users/kapil/PycharmProjects/KapilsucksatPython/py/O.py
16 is not even a multiple of 3
27 is a number, which is 3th power of 3
21 is not a power of 3, but just a multiple of 3
243 is a number, which is 5th power of 3
729 is a number, which is 6th power of 3
```

Process finished with exit code 0